# php diff function - bug when I get the difference between two dates in hours

Tags: php, datetime

I have an issue at **Ex 3** and **Ex 4** when I use diff function to get the difference between two dates.

**Ex 1:**
`$dtFrom = new DateTime('29.03.2020 02:00');`
`$dtTill = new DateTime('29.03.2020 05:00');`
`$interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);`

`echo $interval->format('%h');`
**The result is: 3 (correct)**

**Ex 2:**
`$dtFrom = new DateTime('29.03.2020 02:00');`
`$dtTill = new DateTime('29.03.2020 04:00');`
`$interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);`

`echo $interval->format('%h');`
**The result is: 2 (correct)**

**Ex 3:**
`$dtFrom = new DateTime('29.03.2020 03:00');`
`$dtTill = new DateTime('29.03.2020 05:00');`
`$interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);`

`echo $interval->format('%h');`
**The result is: 1 (incorrect)**

**Ex 4:**
`$dtFrom = new DateTime('29.03.2020 03:00');`
`$dtTill = new DateTime('29.03.2020 06:00');`
`$interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);`

`echo $interval->format('%h');`
**The result is: 2 (incorrect)**

It is a bug or I have done something wrong?
I need an alternative function to do this job in php 5.3.2.
Any ideas?

Comment: Daylight savings time starts on March 29th in Europe and could cause some problems there for you. Not sure if that's the case but I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Indeed the problem apears only on March 29th when is DST but what is the alternative?

Comment: On March 29th EET time zone, the hour 03:00 becomes 
 04:00 and I think this is the cause.

Comment: I posted an answer on how you can avoid the DST adjustments for calculating the difference in hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put UTC timezone in order to avoid DST.

```
  $dtFrom = new DateTime('29.03.2020 03:00',new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  $dtTill = new DateTime('29.03.2020 05:00',new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  $interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);

  echo $interval->format('%h');
```

Comment: PHP takes time zones and DST into account and normally does the right thing but the specific use case of calculating time differences across DST boundaries is known to be buggy. Using UTC as proxy as you suggest is probably the safest course of action.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the same timezone for both DateTime objects you will avoid the DST adjustments:

```
$dtFrom = new DateTime('2020-03-29T03:00:00+02');
$dtTill = new DateTime('2020-03-29T05:00:00+02');
$interval = $dtFrom->diff($dtTill);//2
```

But in other use cases this might lead to other problems.

Comment: +02 is the timezone?

Comment: Yes it is. But I think technically what you deemed wrong in your question is actually the correct difference in hours.